# Computing $\det(3A^2B^3)$ for a $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The question states that $A$ and $B$ are $4\times 4$ matrices, $\det(A) = 2$, and $\det(B) = -3$. Find $\det(3A^2B^3)$.

A classmate helped by showing that $A^2 = 4$, and $4\cdot 3^4$ is $324$. Then $324\cdot -27$ gives a determinant of $-8748$.

What I don't get is when comparing this to another answer. $\det(2A)$ was found by multiplying the original determinant of $2$ by $2^n$, or $2\cdot(2^4)$, or $32$.

So, in my question for the determinant of $3A^2B^3$, why don't you have to multiply by the original determinant? Or is my classmate wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your classmate is correct, and I don't get what is your problem. Do you know that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$? What is "the original determinant"?

Comment: The original determinant of A, which is 2. Which you multiply by 2^n, which equals 32.

Comment: $2^n$ is related to that scalar $2$ multiplying $A$. In fact, the $n \times n$ matrix with only $2$ on the diagonals has determinant $2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of multiplying by $3$ as multiplying by $3I$ instead, the matrix with all diagonal entries 3. The determinant of $3I$ will be $81$ because we have a four by four matrix.

$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}
\right) \; =  \; \; \; 81
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\det(3A^2B^3) = 3^4 \det(A)^2 \det(B)^3 = 81 \cdot 4 \cdot (-27) = -8748$.

Comment: But why don't you have to multiply by the original determinant? That was my main question.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon What do you mean by "the original determinant"? Both $\det A$ and $\det B$ are involved.